# What is the rule for express.static root path?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I ran

```
node src/app.js
```

in the mean-to directory

```
express.static('public')
```

would work,why?

don't need to specify the path?

what's the rule?

and I know

```
__dirname+'/../public'`
```

works just fine.

[image]

---

Just want to make sure the the logic here

I look up the doc
http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

it says

> "Pass the name of the directory that contains the static assets to the express.static middleware function to start serving the files directly. "
>
> "the path that you provide to the express.static function is   ***relative to the directory from where you launch your node process***"

Does that mean

1. if I run **node src/app.js** in *mean-to folder* --> use express.static('public')
2. if I run **node app.js** in *src folder* => use express.static('../public')

and for safety, better use **__dirname** to get the absolute path of the directory

Answer (score 3):

Express static uses [resolve](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_from_to) function from module `path`

Example using `path`:

```
var p = require('path');
p.resolve('public'); // will return your absolute path for `public` directory
```

So rules for express static the same as for `path#resolve` function

You can see more example in the docs for [path](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) module

---

> What's the difference between `p.resolve` and `__dirname`?

### path#resolve

`p.resolve()` resolves to an **absolute** path

```
path.resolve('public');
```

Will return your absolute path for `public`' directory(e.g "`C:\projects\myapp\public`")

```
path.resolve('src'); // => "C:\projects\myapp\src")
```

### __dirname

`__dirname` - name of the directory(absolute path) from which you're currently running your app

file `app.js`

```
console.log(__dirname);
```

Running `node app.js` will print your **absolute** path for your app, e.g "`C:\projects\myapp`"

Comment: what's the difference between p.resolve and __dirname ?

Answer (score 0):

You mixed 2 lines in one... And both are necessary:

```
//This line is to say that the statics files are in public
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public")); 

//This another line is to say that when call the route "/" render a page
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!'); 
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Probably, the reason is in running it from directory highter one level than dir with code? Try run it from src:

```
cd src
node app.js
```